# Validation based on user selection in large form

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I have a user form in which i have multiple fields and based on the type of the user, i have used angular reactive forms and want to validate my fields

Here is my component ts code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

userformGroup: FormGroup;
        Types = [ "user","admin", "guest"];
type: string;

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit() {
 this.userformGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      type: ['user'],
       userName : [''],
      firstName :[''],
      lastName :[''],
        email :[''],
        contactNumber :[''],
        licenseNo :[''],
        age:[''],
        birthDate :[''],
        city:[''],
        country:[''],
        zipCode :[''],
        countryCode:['']
        });
  }

    updateValidators() {
    if (this.type === 'user') {
      this.userformGroup.get('userName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.userformGroup.get('firstName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.userformGroup.get('lastName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.userformGroup.get('email').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.userformGroup.get('contactNumber').setValidators([Validators.required]);
       this.userformGroup.get('licenseNo').setValidators([Validators.required]);
         this.userformGroup.get('age').setValidators([Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]);
       this.userformGroup.get('birthDate').setValidators([Validators.required]);
       this.userformGroup.get('city').setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.userformGroup.get('country').setValidators([Validators.required]);
       this.userformGroup.get('zipCode').setValidators([Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]);
     this.userformGroup.get('countryCode').setValidators([Validators.minLength(3)]);
    }
      else if(this.type === 'admin')
    {
      this.userformGroup.get('userName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.userformGroup.get('firstName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.userformGroup.get('lastName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.userformGroup.get('email').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.userformGroup.get('contactNumber').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('licenseNo').setValidators([Validators.required]);
         this.userformGroup.get('age').setValidators([Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]);
       this.userformGroup.get('birthDate').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('city').setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.userformGroup.get('country').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('zipCode').setValidators([Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]);
     this.userformGroup.get('countryCode').setValidators([Validators.minLength(3)]);    
    }
      else if(this.type === 'guest')
    {
      this.userformGroup.get('userName').setValidators([]);
      this.userformGroup.get('firstName').setValidators([]);
      this.userformGroup.get('lastName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.userformGroup.get('email').setValidators([]);
      this.userformGroup.get('contactNumber').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('licenseNo').setValidators([Validators.required]);
         this.userformGroup.get('age').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('birthDate').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('city').setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.userformGroup.get('country').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('zipCode').setValidators([Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]);
     this.userformGroup.get('countryCode').setValidators([Validators.minLength(3)]);    
    }
     this.userformGroup.get('userName').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('firstName').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('lastName').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('email').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('contactNumber').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('licenseNo').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('age').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('birthDate').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('city').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('country').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('zipCode').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.userformGroup.get('countryCode').updateValueAndValidity();
    }
    onChange(event: any) {
    this.type = event.target.value;
    this.updateValidators();
  }
}
```

This code is working fine, but I'm looking for a optimized way of validating it, how can i do that so that i dont have to repeatedly apply validation on the same fields?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uenuq9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @DeborahK in the link you provided it says: `onlySelf: When true, only update this control. When false or not supplied, update all direct ancestors. Default is false`. It does not update validation status on children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making custom validation functions or writing too much of code in the component, You can use validation based on user's selection by using conditional expression, Here i have used validation from @rxweb validators(RxwebValidators).

The optimal code is :

```
export class UserInfoAddComponent implements OnInit {

    userInfoFormGroup: FormGroup
        Types = [ "user","admin", "guest"];
    constructor(
        private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder
    ) { }

   ngOnInit(){
    this.userInfoFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      type:[''],
      userName :['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })],
      firstName :['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })],
      lastName :['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })],
      email :['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })],     
        contactNumber :['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })],   
      licenseNo :['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })],  
     age:['', RxwebValidators.pattern({expression:{'onlyDigit': /^[0-9]*$/}  ,conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })], 
     birthDate:['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })],
      city:['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })],
      country:['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })],
      zipCode:['',RxwebValidators.pattern({expression:{'zipCode': /^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/}  ,conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })], 
       countryCode:['',RxwebValidators.minLength({value:3,conditionalExpression:(x) => x.type == 'user' })], 


    });


    }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxweb-conditional-required-validator-angular-reactive-fo-xl7drx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-info%2Fadd%2Fuser-info-add.component.ts) working example

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom validator function that applies different validation based on the current user type:

```
requiredForTypes(...types: string[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    if (types.indexOf(this.type) > -1) {
      return Validators.required(control);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then update your Form Controls to use the custom validator:

```
this.userformGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  type: [this.type, Validators.required],
  userName: new FormControl('', this.requiredForTypes('user', 'admin')),
  firstName: new FormControl('', this.requiredForTypes('user', 'admin')),
  lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  email: new FormControl('', this.requiredForTypes('user', 'admin')),
  contactNumber: new FormControl('', this.requiredForTypes('user')),
  licenseNo: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  age: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')),
  birthDate: new FormControl('', this.requiredForTypes('user')),
  city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  country: new FormControl('', this.requiredForTypes('user')),
  zipCode: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')),
  countryCode: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3)),
});
```

Finally, trigger validation whenever the user type changes:

```
this.userformGroup.controls.type.valueChanges.subscribe(type => {
  this.type = type;

  Object.keys(this.userformGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
    if (key !== 'type') {
      this.userformGroup.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  })
});
```

[StackBlitz Example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxenjz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can reorganize your validation conditions.

1. Apply validation directly to declaration that are common to all 3 types.

   ```
   this.userformGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
       type: ['user'],
       userName: [''],
       firstName: [''],
       lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
       email: [''],
       contactNumber: [''],
       licenseNo: ['', [Validators.required]],
       age: [''],
       birthDate: [''],
       city: ['', [Validators.required]],
       country: [''],
       zipCode: ['', [Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]],
       countryCode: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
   });
   ```
2. Reorganize `if else` block in `updateValidators` function

   ```
   if (this.type === 'user' || this.type === 'admin') {
       this.userformGroup.get('userName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
       this.userformGroup.get('firstName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
       this.userformGroup.get('email').setValidators([Validators.required]);
       this.userformGroup.get('age').setValidators([Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]);
   } else {
       this.userformGroup.get('userName').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('firstName').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('email').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('age').setValidators([]);
   }

   if (this.type === 'user') {
       this.userformGroup.get('contactNumber').setValidators([Validators.required]);
       this.userformGroup.get('birthDate').setValidators([Validators.required]);
       this.userformGroup.get('country').setValidators([Validators.required]);
   }
   else {
       this.userformGroup.get('contactNumber').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('birthDate').setValidators([]);
       this.userformGroup.get('country').setValidators([]);
   }
   ```
3. You don't need to call `updateValueAndValidity` on the control's of which validation never changes.

I noticed some other problems with your code.

1. `onChange` function is never getting  called from html.
2. `updateValidators` function not getting called when form initialized. it is required in this case as you are assigning 'user' value to type control. Add these 2 lines after form initialization.

   ```
   this.type = 'user';
   this.updateValidators();
   ```
3. There is a typo in html line 12. should be

   ```
   formControlName="userName"
   ```